# How to disable default logs when using tanstack table?

Tags: reactjs, tanstack, tanstack-table

I am creating table in reactJS using tanstack table and getting this log everytime:

image[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkLqE.png)

I want to disable this default logging. How can I achieve that?
I searched everywhere but not getting any solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the `debugAll={false}` prop.

You can check out the component's documentation [here](https://tanstack.com/table/v8/docs/api/core/table#debugall).